# Software for working with SQL Server databases in Windows Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, windows-server

We have an ASP .NET project that uses SQL Server that we host on a Windows Server 2008 machine. Where does Microsoft keeps its documentation for the tools that can be used for administering SQL Server databases? I'm not sure where to start looking for the software to manage our db.

Comment: Sorry about the shopping list question. If my edit doesn't make it better, I'll eat the downvotes and do better next time.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Management Studio. Download the Express version which, as of SQL Server 2012 Service Pack 1, is fully functional and no longer requires a license and a different installation to gain access to the full set of features. Here is the SP2 version:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43351

The file you want is `SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU.exe` (unless you are on 32-bit, then you want `SQLManagementStudio_x86_ENU.exe`).

There is some pretty good documentation on how to use Management Studio here:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174173(SQL.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174173%28SQL.110%29.aspx)